# How to ensure that ServiceStack always returns JSON?

Tags: json, text, servicestack, http-error

We have decided to only allow requests with a Content-Type header "application/json".
So, whenever we receive a request with an alternative or missing Content-Type header, we throw an HttpError. This *should* return a 400 response containing a JSON ResponseStatus body with relevant info. 
However, if a Content-Type text/plain is sent, we throw an HttpError, but the response's Content-Type is text/plain and content-length: 0. I expected ServiceStack's ResponseStatus to be returned. The ResponseStatus is returned fine if I add an Accept application/json header to the request. 
I executed the request using Postman. Fiddler4 screen shot:
[image]

I am aware that Postman adds the Accept */* header. So my question is: How can I  ensure that a thrown HttpError always return the ResponseStatus as JSON, no matter the request's Accept header?

The SetConfig:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig
        {
            EnableFeatures = Feature.All.Remove( Feature.Html | Feature.Csv | Feature.Jsv | Feature.Xml | Feature.Markdown | Feature.Razor | Feature.Soap | Feature.Soap11 | Feature.Soap12 | Feature.PredefinedRoutes),
            DebugMode = false,
            DefaultContentType = MimeTypes.Json
        });
```

As I understand it, the DefaultContentType is only used whenever there isn't an Accept header in the request.

The PreRequestFilter:

```
PreRequestFilters.Add((request, response) =>
        {
            if (request.Verb.Equals("OPTIONS"))
                response.EndRequest();
            if (request.GetHeader("Content-Type") == null || !request.GetHeader("Content-Type").Equals(MimeTypes.Json))
                throw new HttpError((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Bad request", "Expected a Content-Type header with an application/json value but found none. See http://docsdomain.com/ for any required headers.");
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

The HTTP `Accept` header is what the client uses to indicate what Response Type should be returned but you can override this to always return JSON by adding a Global Request Filter and explicitly setting the `ResponseContentType`, e.g:

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req,res,dto) => 
    req.ResponseContentType = MimeTypes.Json);
```

If the `Accept` Header doesn't specify a specific Response Type it will default to using the `PreferredContentTypes` which you can change by:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    PreferredContentTypes = new []{ MimeTypes.Json }.ToList(),
});
```

Comment: We are validating any request bodies using JSON Schema and, seeing as the vast majority of our end users will prefer JSON, we won't bother implementing the same kind of validation XML bodies.

I have added
`request.ResponseContentType = MimeTypes.Json;`
to my GlobalRespnoseFilter. However, if I throw an HttpError in my PreRequestfilter, the GlobalResponseFilter never gets executed. So I still receive the same Content-Length and Content-Type in my response.
If I add the "forced" Content-type in the PreRequestFilter, my service's parameter's properties are null.

Comment: I just reread your answer and noticed, that you wrote Global**Request**Filter :)
But after adding the line to my GlobalRequestFilter instead of GlobalResponseFilter, the result is the same

Comment: Edit: Not **exactly** the same: any requests with an Accept header value other than <asterisk>/<asterisk> (and of course application/json) now responds with the expected error ResponseStatus.
However, we expect our end users will use Postman to experiment with our API, and since Postman's default Accept header is <asterisk>/<asterisk>, it's not solved 100% yet.
Ps.: <asterisk> = *

Comment: @jk1990 FYI, I've updated my answer to show how to change the preferred Content Type.

Comment: That's nice, and it works: the API now returns JSON, no matter the Accept header. However, I still receive a response with Content-Type text/plain and content-length 0, if the request has a text/plain content-type. In this (possibly very edge case), I want to return a JSON formatted ResponseStatus. 
And despite "forcing" the response Content-type to JSON in the GlobalRequestFilter and removing the Feature.Xml in the Setconfig, if I send a POST with content-type application/xml, the error ResponseStatus body is still formatted as Xml.

Comment: Update: 
The reason why the response had Content-Length: 0 and a Content-Type other than application/json whenever I throw an HttpError in my PreRequestFilter (even though I had `request.ResponseContentType = MimeTypes.Json` in my GlobalRequestFilter) was that the thrown HttpError exited the pipeline, so that my GlobalRequestFilter was never hit. I added `request.ResponseContentType = MimeTypes.Json` to my PreRequestFilter and now it behaves as expected: responding with an application/json ResponseStatus :)