# How to set default content-type to Json with servicestack serializer

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, serialization, servicestack

I want if client did not provide content-type in calling web api, in server side set that to application/json, I found this :

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    PreferredContentTypes = new []{ MimeTypes.Json }.ToList(),
});
```

in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622677/how-to-ensure-that-servicestack-always-returns-json) link
but when I write this code compiler dont recognize Setconfig.

- I set servicestack as default serializer in web api

EDIT:

I followed [this](https://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/replace-json-net-with-servicestack-text-in-asp-net-web-api/) instruction for replacing servicestack.text instead of default serializer of web api.
I dont know where should I put this config, beacuase when I put that in ServiceStackTextFormatter constructor compiler does not recognize SetConfig.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Config.DefaultContentType` e.g:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    DefaultContentType =  MimeTypes.Json
});
```

Comment: SetConfig is a method, right? but I cant find that method in library, compiler complains about that, by the way I try to set this config globally in application start.would you plz tell me if  I should reference something more for have SetConfig?

Comment: SetConfig is where all ServiceStack Configuration is set in your `AppHost.Configure()`. Are you even using [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net)?

Comment: @someone If you're using Web API this question should be "how to set the default ContentType in Web API" as it has nothing to do with ServiceStack. See this post for [configuring WebAPI to only support JSON](https://www.strathweb.com/2013/06/supporting-only-json-in-asp-net-web-api-the-right-way/).